# MySQL Rank Function?

Tags: mysql, sql

How to use rank function in MySQL?
Below is my requirement.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoDtu.jpg)

I need the rank based on FirstName, LastName,MemberID & DOB. If a record matches all the listed four columns then I need to assign rank as above. In oracle I have rank function to obtain the same. How to achieve the same in MySQL?

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't know how insert a table in the textbox. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with variables in SQL Server:

```
select t.*,
       (@rn := if(@v = concat_ws(':', FirstName, LastName, MemberID, DOB), @rn + 1,
                  if(@v := concat_ws(':', FirstName, LastName, MemberID, DOB), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rank  
from t cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @v := '') params
order by FirstName, LastName, MemberID, DOB, lastLoginTime
```

Comment: And why does this have a downvote?  I'm pretty sure this is correct.